# Unable to resize vm

Tags: azure

While trying to resize a `D4s_v3` vm to `D8s_v3` I get the following error:

```
Failed to resize virtual machine 'prod-compass' to size 'Standard D8s v3'. Error: Operation results in exceeding quota limits of Core. Maximum allowed: 10, Current in use: 10, Additional requested: 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to request a core quota increase from Microsoft Support - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/resource-manager-core-quotas-request